# How can i replace the elements inside matrix?

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

my input elements are either 0 or 1... i want to replace 1 with I and 0 with N.

Currently I'm able to read and output the elements, how to replace and output with I and N

```
        System.out.println("Enter the elements of the matrix");
        for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
            for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
                first[i][j] = in.nextInt();

        // Display the elements of the matrix
        System.out.println("Elements of the matrix are");
        for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
                System.out.print(first[i][j] + "\n");
```

Since I'm new to java any help will appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to replace the numbers with characters, the matrix data type should be `char`. Here is an example:

```
int m = 3, n = 3;
char[][] matrix = new char[m][n];
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter the elements of the matrix");
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
     for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
          matrix[i][j] = scan.next().charAt(0);
for(int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++)
        if(matrix[i][j]=='1') 
            matrix[i][j] = 'I';
        else if(matrix[i][j]=='0')
            matrix[i][j] = 'N';
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(matrix));
```

Sample input/output:

```
Enter the elements of the matrix
1
1
1
0
0
0
1
0
1
[[I, I, I], [N, N, N], [I, N, I]]
```

Upon your request, here is how you can scan the characters in the form of `xxx xxx xxx xxx` where x should be 0 or 1 and written according to m and n:

```
int m = 4, n = 3;
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter the elements of the matrix");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    String inp = scan.nextLine();
    while (inp.length() != n || !inp.matches("[01]+")) {
        System.out.println("Warning: input must be "+n+" characters and only 1 or 0.");
        inp = scan.nextLine();
    }
    sb.append(inp+" ");
}
String str = sb.toString().trim().replaceAll("1", "I");
str = str.replaceAll("0", "N");
System.out.println(str);
```

Sample input/output:

```
Enter the elements of the matrix
112
Warning: input must be 3 characters and only 1 or 0.
111
000
101
010
III NNN INI NIN
```

Comment: But actually im taking the input from console like this  in = new Scanner(System.in);
            m = in.nextInt();
            n = in.nextInt();

Comment: Why don't you read the input as character or string instead?

Comment: @JordanMong I updated the answer to fill the matrix with characters as well.

Comment: Thank you very much! you are  very helpful. Just one more thing, is there anyway i can read inputs like this - m is 4 and n is 3.. like together rows together
110
000
110
000

Comment: You mean the user would input it once?

Comment: yes, after taking m and n values. How can i read column wise with respect to value n.

Comment: So this way, you want to make sure that the number of space-separated words is equal to ``m`` and the length of each word is equal to ``n``? And then fill the matrix or just replace the characters of the string?

Comment: Im trying taking to take input from user for rows and columns. for e.g if he gives 2X3 matrix then input will be 101 111 or if he gives 4X2  then it will be 11 01 00 10. No space or enter in between while reading column

Comment: after reading i have to replace with I and N and display in the same format which input was taken. Damn its a bit of task for me, since im new to java i need to get some help. But im grateful that you were to give some information. Thanks!

Comment: @JordanMong I added a way to read the input as you requested.

Comment: You're awesome! pro stuff!!! is there anyway i can modify the output to get it vertically instead of horizontal like this -- IIN
NNN
IIN
NNN

Comment: for(String s : str.split(" ")) System.out.println(s);

Comment: Hello my friend sorry to bother you again! Is there anyway i could i could loop over number of matrix at once for input. eg 3
4 3
110
000
110
000
2 3
101
000
2 2
10
01 where 3 is number of loops and rest are same as before m and n's

Comment: You can use a simple for loop according to the first number and save your matrices in a list or array

Comment: Yes, i made a loop and im taking the input --- Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = sc.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
            readMatrix();
        } But it executes only for first matrix and stops